# C#でインスタンスを通してstaticメソッドを呼べない

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
class playerstatus{
    public static　int coin=100;
}

class sample {
    cointext.text = "coins: " + playerstatus.coin.ToString();
}
```

こうするとcs0176がでて`Static member 'playerstatus.coin' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead`

これは仕様らしいのですが、他の方法はありますでしょうか

Comment: 呈示されたコード片は質問内容を正しく反映していませんし文法的にも成立してないので、現実のコードに即した適切なコードに修正してください

Comment: 「文法的にも成立してない」というのは「質問の箇所以外にも」ということです。

Comment: coinって何型の変数でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`cointext.text = "coins: " + playerstatus.coin.ToString();` の部分が文脈的に書けない（クラス内の地の文としては書けない）ので質問内容を再現するようなコードになっていません。
以下のコードは期待するように実行できますから実際のコードとは異なる（インスタンスからの呼び出しをしていない）ように思います。

```
using System;

class playerstatus{
    public static int coin=100;
}

class sample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "coins: " + playerstatus.coin.ToString();//文字列との結合で変換されるのでToString()は必要無い
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        /* おそらく質問者の状況はこういうことをしていると思われる
        playerstatus p = new playerstatus();
        Console.WriteLine(p.coin);//coin はインスタンスのメンバーではないのでできない。スタティックなメンバーはクラス名から呼び出す。（エラーメッセージの通り）
        */
    }
}
```