# staticを使って他の静的なクラスにアクセスする方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

例えば

sampleclassに

public static int sample

sample = 10;

というものがあったとします。

これを sample2のクラスに

sampleをstaticとして入れる方法はありますでしょうか。　　c#です

Comment: 重複候補: [C#でインスタンスを通してstaticメソッドを呼べない](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18740/c%e3%81%a7%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%82%92%e9%80%9a%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6static%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bd%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%82%92%e5%91%bc%e3%81%b9%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 2):

プロパティを使用すれば`sample2`内で見かけ上は`sampleclass.sample`直接にアクセスすることが可能です。

```
class sample2
{
    private static int sample
    {
        get
        {
            return sampleclass.sample;
        }
        set
        {
            sampleclass.sample = value;
        }
    }
}
```

ただし真のフィールドではありませんので、参照としては使用できません。

またC#6.0であれば`using static sampleclass`で`sampleclass`を省略してメソッドを呼び出し可能です。

Comment: コンパイルするとerror CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static memberと出てしまいます・・・

Comment: @user0101  `sampleclass.sample`が`static`ではないのでは